# Tensorflow Serving: Large model, protobuf error

Tags: c++, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to make serve a big (1.2 GB in size) model with Tensorflow Serving, but I am getting a:

```
2017-12-02 21:55:57.711317: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:236] Loading SavedModel from: ...
[libprotobuf ERROR external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc:193] A protocol message was rejected because it was too big (more than 1073741824 bytes).  To increase the limit (or to disable these warnings), see CodedInputStream::SetTotalBytesLimit() in google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h.
2017-12-02 21:55:58.563507: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:284] Loading SavedModel: fail. Took 852178 microseconds.
2017-12-02 21:55:58.563567: E tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:38] Loading servable: {name: 2 version: 2} failed: Data loss: Can't parse .../saved_model.pb as binary proto
```

I read through a few related issues on Github from a few years ago, but ultimately it turned unrelated, since Serving is using the C++ version of the protobuf. There is little information on deploying large models with Serving, so any information would suffice.

Tensorflow Serving was compiled on the host machine, so was the model, but using python3 (I wonder if it has to do with anything at all).
Is there a quick fix for this, or I have to dig through the Serving C++ sources and increase the size of the message?

**Edit per request in the comments:**

I save the model according to the official tutorial. The reason why the model is so big is that I have an embedding layer saved along. Here is the saving code anyway:

```
export_path = 'model/1'
builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

signature = predict_signature_def(inputs={'input': input},
                                  outputs={'sent': output})


builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess=session,
                                     tags=[tag_constants.SERVING],
                                     signature_def_map={'predict': signature})
builder.save()
```

The model is read by a compiled TF Serving from GitHub on a Ubuntu 16.04 host.

Comment: Can you also type how you write and read the model?

Comment: @DenizBeker I have updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it helps someone, but I "found" a solution.

The major problem was obvious; his is an NLP model, thus it has a big vocabulary that goes along with it. Leaving the vocabulary in the graph definition bloats the metagraphdef, and protobuf is giving an error when faced with such a big protocol.

The solution would to put the dictionary in the **assets_collection**. There is little documentation to what you actually have to do, but looking at the [saved_model_test.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/saved_model_test.py#L552) at the official repo is worth looking at.

As to utilize the assets with Tensorflow Serving, one has to create a custom Servable, as described in the [Creating a new kind of servable](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/custom_servable)  official documentation. Cannot provide a specific example, because I simply containerized the model for the time being.

If anyone has examples, or has a better strategy when it comes to NLP models deployment, I would be happy to discuss it further.